# what is wrong with this javascript accordion code?

Tags: javascript, accordion

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
var activePanel = document.querySelector('.active');
var hiddenPanel = document.querySelectorAll("section > div:not(.active)");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      var otherPanels = document.querySelectorAll("section > div:not(.active)");

      panel.classList.add('.active');
      otherPanels.classList.add('.hidden');

    }
  });

};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn {
  color: white;
  background-color: brown;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.panel {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="accordion">
    <h3 class="btn">button1</h3>
    <div class="panel">panel1</div>

    <h3 class="btn">button2</h3>
    <div class="panel">panel2</div>

    <h3 class="btn">button3</h3>
    <div class="panel">panel3</div>

    <h3 class="btn">button4</h3>
    <div class="panel">panel4</div>
  </section>

</body>
```

Hello,

please I am trying to code a javascript accordion, but my code does not work

what I want to do is when I click on button, it shows its panel only by adding active class to this panel only and adding hidden class to all other panels at the same time

so when I click on button it toggles sliding up and down

and only one panel shows then when I click on other button it slide down its own panel and automatically slide up the other panel

please help and many thanks in advance

Comment: there is a syntax error in ur code .
remove `}` after `otherPanels.classList.add('.hidden');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to guys who already mentioned syntax errors and other fixes. You don't need any loops, array processings like in forEach and so on, and many event listeners for each button. Here is plain and simple solution with event listener on section:

```
let section = document.querySelector('#accordion');

section.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if(!event.target.classList.contains('btn')) return;

  let activePanel = section.querySelector('.active');
  let clickedPanel = event.target.nextElementSibling;

  clickedPanel.classList.add('active');
  activePanel && activePanel.classList.remove('active');
});
```

No loops, only one event listener, and you work only with one current element and one previously active (if any)!

Hope it helps

Comment: @ evhenious     thanks a lot it works as I want it, but could you explain more why do you chose section element and what is the use of the rule of if not and return. I deleted it from the code and the code works too and what is return here 2- if the target of the event here is the section element , what is its nextElementSibling here? as the section is the parent and it does not have any siblings . and many thanks in advance

Comment: @social it is simple:
1. single event handler on section allows to process all clicks on child buttons, so we don't need to have event handler per button, and we can handle all we need in one place. And of course 1 function better than 4 :) maybe in this simple case it does not matter, but in general it can save you some RAM
2. `if(!event.target.classList.contains('btn')) return` - as we process clicks from all children, this allows us to ignore clicks on any other items except buttons. If you would add anything into opening panels, this could help to ignore not required clicks

Comment: 3. nextElementSibling from clicking on element returns null if it is last element on the same hierarchy level. So, clicking on section gives null. And clicking on the last panel (panel4) also gives null! So, have a look at described condition in p.2 - if we not ignore all clicks except on buttons, we could get few errors. Hope it helps

Comment: @evhenious I must say, yours is the most elegant solution among all the answers in this thread.

Comment: @evhenious Thanks so much for your detailed reply. your code it very simple. with just few rules we can achieve the exact reult I want. thanks for explaining. I really do appreciate

Comment: @social I'm happy to help

Answer (score 1):

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
var activePanel = document.querySelector('.active');
var hiddenPanel = document.querySelectorAll("section > div:not(.active)");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (panel.classList.contains('active')) {
          panel.classList.remove('active');
          panel.classList.add('hidden');
      } else {
          var otherPanels = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("section > div"));
          otherPanels.forEach(p => p.classList.add('hidden'));
          panel.classList.remove('hidden');
          panel.classList.add('active');
      }
    }
  );
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn {
  color: white;
  background-color: brown;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.panel {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="accordion">
    <h3 class="btn">button1</h3>
    <div class="panel">panel1</div>

    <h3 class="btn">button2</h3>
    <div class="panel">panel2</div>

    <h3 class="btn">button3</h3>
    <div class="panel">panel3</div>

    <h3 class="btn">button4</h3>
    <div class="panel">panel4</div>
  </section>

</body>
```

Comment: @ Pawan Kumar
           thanks so much, it works well, but when I click on a button it shows its panel and hides other panels but when I click again on the same button at the same time, it does not hide its panel. I have tried toggle but it did not work very well

Comment: @social Can you try now.

Comment: @ Pawan Kumar    thanks so much. it works better hide and show but it needs to click double click on the button to shows its panel if the other button is not exactly below the previous clicked button. just want to click one click not double to show the panel and many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Change your JavaScript code to the following:

```
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
var activePanel = document.querySelector('.active');
var hiddenPanel = document.querySelectorAll("section > div:not(.active)");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var otherPanels = document.querySelectorAll("section > div");
      otherPanels.forEach(function (panel) {
        panel.classList.remove('hidden');
        panel.classList.remove('active');
      });


      var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      console.log(panel);
      panel.classList.add('active');

      var otherPanels = document.querySelectorAll("section > div:not(.active)");
      otherPanels.forEach(function (panel) {
        panel.classList.add('hidden');
      });
    });
}
```

Code here:
https://codepen.io/v08i/pen/RwNBJKN

Comment: @ Tuna       thanks so much, it works well, but when I click on a button it shows its panel and hides other panels but when I click again on the same button at the same time, it does not hide its panel. I have tried toggle but it did not work very well

Comment: @social I have updated the code in pen. Please check `https://codepen.io/v08i/pen/RwNBJKN`

Comment: @ Tuna yes thanks it toggles show and hide now for the same panel but if I did not hide it by myself after showing it then I click on other button it shows its own panel too but the other panels remain showing unless I hide them by myself. I just want it to hides itself automatically when I click new button not by myself but automatically. and many thanks in advance

Comment: @social Sorry, I messed up earlier. Check now and it should work as expected.

Comment: yes thanks so much. now it works perfectly exactly as I want, but could you explain more please. I got confused about two things: 1- the variable otherPanels has two different defined values. although the same variable should have one value?         2- I got confused about adding and removing the active and hidden classes. for example first you removed the hidden class although none of the panels had it because it was just on the code of CSS not HTML. just want to know how adding and removing those classes work on the code.  I really do appreciate and many thanks in advance. thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

```
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
var activePanel = document.querySelector('.active');
var hiddenPanel = document.querySelectorAll("section > div:not(.active)");

var i;

for (i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      var otherPanels = document.querySelectorAll("section > div.active");
        otherPanels.forEach((item) => {item.classList.remove('active');})
      panel.classList.add('active');


    }
  );

};
```

Don't use hidden class as you have already added "`display:none`" in `.panel` class , so you just need to remove and add `active` class

Comment: `var otherPanels = document.querySelector("section > div.active");
if(otherPanels)
      otherPanels.classList.remove('active');`
@evhenious You are right , i missed it in hurry.

Comment: @  pratik kaneria      thanks so much, it works well, but when I click on a button it shows its panel and hides other panels but when I click again on the same button at the same time, it does not hide its panel. I have tried toggle but it did not work very well